# Autoassign values to character strings in R during import

Tags: r, import, dataframe

```
Type      Force
A         30
A         40
B         20
C         10
C         14
```

I have a dataset like the one above, I am importing from CSV, like this. I am converting the Type to a factor.

```
Data <- read.csv(csvImport)
Data <- within(Data, 
{ 
    Type <-  factor(as.character(Data[[Type]] )       
})
```

However, when I convert this to a data matrix for downstream processing, The values autoconvert to integers, which is fair.

```
x <- data.matrix(Data)
```

Is there anyway to revert it back to the character/string values **after I process my data**, so that when doing the final print, instead of 1,2, and 3 I have back A, B and C ?

Or in other words, when I convert it to a factor during import, is there anyway to assign values to it, something along the lines of this..?

```
Type <- factor ( i++, labels=as.character(Data[[Type]])
```

Here's a step by step on what I want to achieve

1. Take in a list of strings from a column of a table from a csv import
2. Convert the strings into a factor and autoassign an int as the
   value, and  the input string as the label of that int

If this can be relatively automated so that end users can load a csv file without having to assign labels manually, and have integers automatically loaded that'd be helpful.

This would hopefully allow me to work on the data in a data frame itself and not convert it into a datamatrix which strips my labels off.

**EDIT:**

```
y <- rapply(Data,mean,classes="numeric")
```

Seems to work as a workaround, as I don't have to convert to a data matrix. However in the resulting output of y, I am losing the     Type. That  should be fixable. Still am interested in knowing if this can be done more elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

When you read the file in, you read it in to a data frame. As this is a list of vectors, the `Type` vector is factor and the `Force` vector is integer. I.e., they can be different because a data frame can handle different types. This can be confirmed with:

```
is(Data$Type)
is(Data$Force)
```

When you convert to a data matrix, however, all columns must be of the same type, so `Type` is being converted to an integer to match `Force`:

```
Data <- data.matrix(Data)
is(Data[[1]])  # should be numeric
```

See @hadley 's [Advanced R: Data Structures chapter] which is a superb reference.[1](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html)

The simplest solution is to stick with a data frame, unless you *need* to use a data matrix for some reason. If you must use a data matrix you can convert back to a data frame and explicitly label the variable again using `labels` argument in `factor`:

```
Data <- data.frame(Data)
Data$Type <- factor(Data$Type, levels = c(1:3),
                    labels = c("A",
                               "B",
                               "C"))
```

Comment: The reason I need to use a datamatrix is I have to apply(x,2,mean) and take the mean and sd of each column. If I leave it as a dataframe, the apply function doesnt like it for some reason.

Comment: I've edited my question to include how to convert back to a factor with labels

Comment: You won't be able to calculate the mean of a variable like `Type` if it's coded as a factor. Do you get an error like: > Warning message:
In mean.default(Data$Type) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: will factor(Data$Type, levels = c(1:length(Data$Type),levels=c(Data$Type)) )also work? am off to try..

Comment: The second argument is `labels` (you have `levels` twice). Regardless, it probably won't work because the labels were stripped when converting to `data.matrix`. Also, `1:length(Data$Type)` is wrong because you actually want three levels (A, B, C), not the length of the vector (which is 5).

Comment: Yeah, the error is as you said in the 3rd comment. Thats why I am trying to get it done in a data matrix as that works. The thing is I dont want to manually assign the labels in factors, as the end user ] will have more than 3. One way to go about it is to ask the end user to prep the input file without any characters, but I dont want to do that if it can be avoided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77437/discussion-between-phil-and-rover-eye).

Answer (score 1):

How about using `levels`

```
vec.letters <- paste(letters,sep="")
levels(vec.letters)<- 1:length(vec.letters)
```

then

```
vec.letters
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x"
[25] "y" "z"
attr(,"levels")
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Or possibly a more functional solution:

```
vec.three.ltrs <- c("A", "B", "C")
codes = c(A=1,B=2,C=3)
new.vec = sapply(vec.three.ltrs,function(x)codes[x])
```

which would give you:

```
> new.vec
A.A B.B C.C 
  1   2   3
```

Comment: This can work, but I am trying to get the script to autoassign the labels rather than me manually assigning them / hard coding them.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make this more explicit. Also if you want to open a new question we can help you use `apply` to find the means of numeric columns in a data frame if that gets around your issue.

Comment: @RoverEye Are there values for letters predefined, if you simply want to get numeric value you could use `utf8ToInt` and use the following numbers any way you please. You could modify the integers to correspond to more sensible numbers.

Comment: @Konrad interesting. If I do a utf8toint conversion, I'll however get multiple numbers (2 numbers for each character in my Type). I should have mentioned in my question that the types are not simple A and Bs They are alphanumeric, representing something biologically. I'll play around with this idea. Thanks.

Comment: @RoverEye alternatively you could consider making use of the `strtoi` on the lines: `> strtoi(c("AA", "BB", "C"), base = 36)` and adjust the base accordingly. Depending on how many letters you have you may be willing to code your letters in hexadecimal or other system. However, if I think it, it becomes fruitless as in effect you replace letter with another letter.